# Row number generating for repeated clients - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple row_number based query that is not producing me the desired result:

```
create table #fake(client_id int)
insert #fake
values(1991) ,(1991),(1992)

select distinct
    _row_ord = 100,
    _client_id =  c.client_id,
    _segment = 'fake',
    --_row = row_number() over(order by c.client_id)
    _value = 
        concat
                (
                'HL*',
                row_number() over(order by c.client_id) + 1 ,'*',
                'testfield','~' 
                )
from #fake c 

drop table #fake
```

**So my current output is:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

I am realizing that my row_number query is missing something. Any help?

Comment: also partition by is your friend

Comment: @ZoharPeled the link is identical to his actual output?

Comment: oops that +1 is my logic. I will edit my question now

Comment: @DougCoats oops, sorry, I mixed up the current and desired output...

Comment: z'all good edited his post to make it more clear

Comment: @DougCoats it doesn't offend me but splattering curse words in your comments is likely going to get you blocked. Keep it professional.

Comment: @SeanLange sorry i like what i do - but i should try to be more clean cut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `row_number()` to `dense_rank()` to get the desired results:

```
select distinct
    _row_ord = 100,
    _client_id =  c.client_id,
    _segment = 'fake',
    --_row = row_number() over(order by c.client_id)
    _value = 
        concat
                (
                'HL*',
                dense_rank() over(order by c.client_id) + 1 ,'*',
                'testfield','~' 
                )
```

Results:

```
_row_ord    _client_id  _segment    _value
100         1991        fake        HL*2*testfield~
100         1992        fake        HL*3*testfield~
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/FKWB7624)